# Libgdx - How to rotate a single ShapeRenderer object

Tags: java, libgdx

So, looked at a couple of questions similar to this, led me straight into dead ends. I have an object drawn out in `ShapeRenderer`, and I wish to rotate **only** that one object. I have tried `shapeRenderer.rotate(x, y, 1, 1)`, however all of my `ShapeRenderer` objects rotate. Anyone know how one would go about rotating a single `ShapeRenderer` object that is defined by an array of vertices? I've posted how I have drawn my object below.

```
    //LEFT
    shapex[0] = x - 59/2;
    shapey[0] = y + 53/2;

    shapex[1] = x - 18/2;
    shapey[1] = y + 30/2 ;

    shapex[2] = x - 6/2;
    shapey[2] = y + 53/2;

    shapex[3] = x - 16/2;
    shapey[3] = y -51/2;


    shapex[4] = x - 21/2;
    shapey[4] = y + 1/2;
```

EDIT: I have tried to use polygon, however I see no good tutorials showing how to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @drumbumLOLcatz says, there are a bunch of overloaded methods when you create your shapes, what you are looking are for those methods that involve a `degree`parameter. Something like this:

```
public void rect(float x, float y, float originX, float originY, float width, 
                 float height, float scaleX, float scaleY, float degrees)
```

So everytime you call the `shapeRenderer` object, you must specify this parameters for each shape that you want to transform (in this case, rotate):

```
shapeRenderer.begin();
// more code
shapeRenderer.rect(x, y, oX, oY, w, h, sX, sY, degrees);
// more code
shapeRenderer.end();
```

As you don't say if you are using complex shapes, I don't know if this will satisfy your question (since I don't know if you are drawing simple lines, quadrilaterals, circles, arcs, etc.). If you are using the `Polygon` class, this should be easier, since this class can manage the rotation individually.

To draw a polygon, first, you construct your shape with your vertices, something like this:

```
// this are the vertices for a simple quadrilateral
float[] vertices = new float[] {
    0,   0,
    100, 0,
    100, 100,
    0,   100
};
// Create the polygon
Polygon polygon = new Polygon();
polygon.setVertices(vertices);
```

Then, if you want, you could rotate this polygon:

```
polygon.rotate(degrees);
```

And draw it:

```
shapeRenderer.begin();
// more code
shapeRenderer.polygon(polygon.getTransformedVertices());
// more code
shapeRenderer.end();
```

But, take in count that this will only draw the outline, in order to fill your shape you must consider another option like the `Mesh` class, triangulating your complex shape.

Comment: Nice, this works perfectly how I needed it to. Yes, I'm using complex polygons, so I added a radian factor to it. My shapes can go beyond 132 individual points, where I spend at least 2 minutes per point, so that time adds up. Would making a new class that took in point inputs and converted them from polar to cartesian coordinates work best to save a lot of time?

Answer (score -1):

When you draw a shape, there is sometimes a degree parameter (at least when you draw a rect)  http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/glutils/ShapeRenderer.html#rect-float-float-float-float-float-float-float-float-float-

EDIT:  also, any libgdx Shape Class will have a rotate function.  Maybe instead of keeping your shapes in arrays of x and y, make an array of Polygons.

Docs: http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/math/Polygon.html#rotate-float-

Comment: Please give more details in your answer.

Comment: Yea, looks like it's only for rectangles. I wanted my shape to point towards the mouse, so I added a MathUtils.cos(radians) and MathUtils.sin(radians) factor to shapex and shapey, however that didn't work. The shape seemed to rotate across the x and y axis instead of the z axis.

Comment: Edited my answer to link to the rotate function.  Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the refs, now I just need to figure out how to use  these.

Comment: Nope, still have no clue how to do it. I don't know how to properly draw the polygon.